# PHP create nested directories

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

I need help with a function to create a 2 level directory for the following situations:

1. The desired sub-directory exists in the parent directory, do nothing.
2. Parent directory exists, sub-directory does not exist. Create only the sub-directory.
3. Neither parent directory, nor the sub-directory exists, First create parent directory, then sub-directory.
4. If Any of the directory was not created successfully, return FALSE.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the third parameter of [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/mkdir):

> **recursive** Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname. Defaults to FALSE.

```
$path = '/path/to/folder/with/subdirectory';
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
```

Comment: @Paulocoghi You are right. This behaviour is different from Linux' `mv`, which simply ignores existing paths

Comment: use
if(!is_dir($path)) {
      mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}

Answer (score 6):

recursive Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname.
but did not work for me!!
for that here is what i came up with!! and it work very perfect!!

```
$upPath = "../uploads/RS/2014/BOI/002";   // full path 
$tags = explode('/' ,$upPath);            // explode the full path
$mkDir = "";

    foreach($tags as $folder) {          
        $mkDir = $mkDir . $folder ."/";   // make one directory join one other for the nest directory to make
        echo '"'.$mkDir.'"<br/>';         // this will show the directory created each time
        if(!is_dir($mkDir)) {             // check if directory exist or not
          mkdir($mkDir, 0777);            // if not exist then make the directory
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try using [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en//function.file-exists.php) to check if a folder exists or not and `is_dir` to check if it is a folder or not.

```
 if(file_exists($dir) && is_dir($dir))
```

And to create a directory you can use the `mkdir` function

Then the rest of your question is just manipulating this to suit the requirements

Answer (score 1):

See [`mkdir`](http://www.php.net/mkdir), in particular the `$recursive` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

How much i suffered.. and got this script..

```
function recursive_mkdir($dest, $permissions=0755, $create=true){
    if(!is_dir(dirname($dest))){ recursive_mkdir(dirname($dest), $permissions, $create); }  
    elseif(!is_dir($dest)){ mkdir($dest, $permissions, $create); }
    else{return true;}
}
```

Comment: Is this just not formatted or do you seriously write code like this?

Comment: @buffalo, if had seriously read the information about answer (either my comment `got this script` or even post date) it says enough. moreover, you could just edit post, instead of irony, you had enough rep ;) cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with PHP 8 (2020-11-24), you can use named parameters:

```
<?php
mkdir('March/April', recursive: true);
```

https://php.net/function.mkdir

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is MKDIR.
Use the last parameter to recursively create directories. And [read the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.0+ [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) has a recursive parameter which will create any missing parents.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Desired folder structure
$structure = './depth1/depth2/depth3/';

// To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
// to mkdir() must be specified.

if (!mkdir($structure, 0744, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
```

[PHP: mkdir - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_dir and mkdir

```
if (!is_dir($path)) 
{
    @mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}
```